# Default button size?

Tags: winapi

How do I create a button control (with `CreateWindow` of a `BUTTON` window class) that has a standard system-wide size (especially height) that's consistent with the rest of Windows applications?
I should of course take DPI into account and probably other settings.

> **Remark:** Using `USE_CW_DEFAULT` for width and height results in a 0, 0 size button, so that's not a solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### In the perfect, hassle-free world...

To create a standard size button we would have to do this:

```
LONG units = GetDialogBaseUnits();
m_hButton = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Close"), 
                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 
                 0, 0, MulDiv(LOWORD(units), 50, 4), MulDiv(HIWORD(units), 14, 8),
                 hwnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);
```

where **50** and **14** are respective DLU dimensions, **4** and **8** are horizontal and vertical dialog template units respectively, based on [`GetDialogBaseUnits()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdialogbaseunits) documentation remarks.

---

### Nothing's perfect

**BUT** as Anders pointed out, those metrics are based on the system font. If your window uses a shell dialog font or simply anything not making your eyes bleed, you're pretty much on your own.

To get your own "dialog" base units, you have to retrieve current text metrics with `GetTextMetrics()` and use character height and average width (`tmHeight` and `tmAveCharWidth` of the `TEXTMETRIC` struct respectively) and translate them with MulDiv on your own, **unless** you are in a dialog, then `MapDialogRect()` will do all the job for you.

Note that `tmAveCharWidth` only approximates the actual average character width so it's recommended to use a [`GetTextExtentPoint32()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gettextextentpoint32a?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function on an alphabetic character set instead.

See:

- [Q145994: HOWTO: Calculate Dialog Units When Not Using the System Font](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/145/Q145994/)
- [How does the dialog manager calculate the average width of a character?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20221103-00/?p=107350)

---

### Simpler alternative

If buttons are the only control you want to resize automatically, you can also use [`BCM_GETIDEALSIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bcm-getidealsize) message [`Button_GetIdealSize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-button_getidealsize) macro (Windows XP and up only) to retrieve optimal width and height that fits anything the button contains, though it looks pretty ugly without any margins applied around the button's text.

Comment: In an even more perfect world, GUI layout in 2009 wouldn't involve pixel coordinates at all. :) Dynamic layout managers are a better solution in the majority of cases, imo.

Comment: Amen to that! :) 

Although even in this pixel-ridden Win32 world, you've got some helpful functions for that, so you never have to deal with pixel coordinates explicitly.

Comment: yup, `BCM_GETIDEALSIZE` gives you shooty dims

Comment: Both links in the middle section are dead. Retrieved from the WayBack Machine: First one: http://web.archive.org/web/20140608215304/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/145994 Second One: http://web.archive.org/web/20131208002908/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/125681 (Edit suggested)

Comment: Keep in mind that you also need a specific font size, font of height 11 will give you exact same dimensions of a button as default ones in system dialogs.

Answer (score 10):

This is what MSDN has to say: [Design Specifications and Guidelines - Visual Design: Layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997619.aspx).

The default size of a button is 50x14 DLUs, which can be calculated to pixels using the examples shown for [GetDialogBaseUnits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645475(VS.85).aspx).

The [MapDialogRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645502(VS.85).aspx) function seems to do the calculation for you.

Comment: MapDialogRect doesn't help if your window is not a dialog unfortunately, but calculating by hand works very well.

Answer (score 1):

@macbirdie: you should NOT use GetDialogBaseUnits(), it is based on the default system font (Ugly bitmap font). You should use MapDialogRect()

Comment: As I mentioned in a previous comment, MapDialogRect doesn't work for non-dialog windows, so I guess I have to try the GetTextExtentPoint32 and GetTextMetrics functions as suggested.